# Route discovery between master slave and slave slave

Tags: python, networking, ping, master-slave, traceroute

I have a master node and different slave nodes. I want to perform traceroute from each slave to every other slave and master and send this route to master periodically with timestamp.

Bruteforce approach seems to be performing a traceroute from each slave to different slaves and then send to master.

I have tried calling `traceroute` using `subprocess` from my python script. But it takes a lot of time in generating the output and then sending the traceroute to master would again take a lot of time.

My main purpose is to store the routes in master and whenever any slaves fails i can get the latest route from these logs which i have stored in the master.

I have looked for other library tools as well such as `scapy` python library and `mtr`.

Any pointers on how to do this in best possible way ?

Thanks

Comment: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Comment: @RonMaupin edited the question